# GREP for multiple strings with wildcard

Tags: linux, command-line, php, grep

I am trying to copy lines from a log file from certain days.

Here's an example of what they look like.

```
2014-05-01T15:53:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): 

2014-04-301T11:08:10+00:00 DEBUG (7):
```

This GREP command works but only for exact strings:

> `grep -w '2014-04-30\|2014-04-29\|2014-04-28\|2014-04-27\|2014-04-26\|2014-04-25\|2014-04-24\|2014-04-23\|2014-04-22\|2014-04-21\|2014-04-202014-04-19' /test_custom.log > new_file.log`

When I try to add the wildcard, it doesn't work. I also tried several other ways with same result.

> `grep -w '2014-04-30*\|2014-04-29*\|2014-04-28*\|2014-04-27*\|2014-04-26*\|2014-04-25*\|2014-04-24*\|2014-04-23*\|2014-04-22*\|2014-04-21*\|2014-04-20*' /test_custom.log > new_file.log`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` in a regular expression has a different meaning than in a filename wildcard. `*` means *repeat the preceding thing zero or more times*. To just say "anything", you have to use `.*`, where `.` stands for "any character".

Moreover, if you want all lines that start with the dates, drop the `-w` and add `^` to match the beginnings of lines:

```
grep '^\(2014-04-30\|2014-04-29\|2014-04-28\|2014-04-27\)'
```

The dates are enblosed in parentheses so you don't have to repeat the `^` every time.